# UnauthorizedAccessException when creating XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 XAML/C# Metro app.

Currently, I am getting an authorization error when trying to save an XML document. Here is the method that when run throws:

```
   public async void saveXML(string fileName)
   {
       Windows.Storage.StorageFolder sf = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.CreateFolderAsync("XML");
       StorageFile st = await sf.CreateFileAsync(fileName);
       await SyncXMLDoc.SaveToFileAsync(st);
   }
```

Here is the specific error:

- $exception  {"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"} System.Exception {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}

How do I resolve this? Why would I not be allowed to create an XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not write files to the application's install directory. From the [File access and permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)  article on MSDN:

> The app's install directory is a read-only location.

You have to save your files to one of the Application Data Folders, also explained in that article.